# Regex for replacing forward slash after a colon

Tags: java, regex

I am looking at java regex for the following

Input:  `pqr/abc:/xyz/gef/lmn   mno/def:/abc/def/ghi`
Output: `pqr/abc:\\/xyz\\/gef\\/lmn mno/def:\\/abc\\/def\\/ghi`

So basically we need to replace the text to right of a colon(:) which has "forward slash" with `\\/`  i.e escaping the forward slash

Comment: you mean double backslash?

Comment: Yes with a double backslash, but only to the right of colon and the left side text of colon should be untouched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\G` anchor in-order to do a continuous string match. The anchor `\G` matches at the position where the previous match ended. Read more about `\G` anchor from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).

```
String r = "pqr/abc:/xyz/gef/lmn mno/def:/abc/def/ghi";
System.out.println(r.replaceAll("((?::|(?<!^)\\G)[^/\\s]*)(/)", "$1\\\\\\\\$2"));
```

**Output:**

```
pqr/abc:\\/xyz\\/gef\\/lmn mno/def:\\/abc\\/def\\/ghi
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iX8pE7/4)

Comment: What if the input is pqr/abc:*/xyz/gef/lmn/*   mno/def:*/abc/def/ghi/* and the expected output is  pqr/abc:*\\/xyz\\/gef\\/lmn\\/* mno/def:\\/abc\\/def\\/ghi\\/* the * are literals

Comment: check my update.. here is the demo https://regex101.com/r/iX8pE7/6

Comment: awesome, thanks! This looked easy but when we went for a solution only a regex guru can solve this. appreciate the time.

Comment: Have a new requirement with this input is  pqr/abc:*/xyz/gef/lmn/* mno/def:*/abc/def/ghi/* and output is  pqr/abc:\"*/xyz/gef/lmn/*\" mno/def:\"*/abc/def/ghi/*\"   so bottom line is if we find forward slash after a colon we just make it as a term inside quotes and escaping it.

Comment: please ask it as a new question.